# Is it possible to export actual python code of Flowise generated LLM apps?

Tags: large-language-model, llama-index, flowise

I am able to create no code LLM apps via flowise, it also provides an api to access it. But I want to get the actual code, which is running behind the scene. Is it possible to get?

There is nothing mentioned in documentation

Answer (score 0):

The code that makes Flowise run is entirely open source on [github](https://github.com/FlowiseAI/Flowise).
But if I do understand your question correctly, this will not be exactly what you are looking for.

Flowise is not generating Python scripts in the background that you can easily integrate. It consists of a (complex) runtime that interprets and runs the visual flow that you designed through its own "engine".
This engine is also exposing API endpoints, that you can call from Python. This will still require some knowledge of Python, and you can find an example [here](https://github.com/ZynthCode/flowise-ai-with-python) to get you on your way.
Probably not entirely what you expected for but I still hope it helps!